# Can't access Google Docs with different email?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-account, google-drive-sharing

I have a google account. Someone sent a link to access a google doc to my email me@somedomain.com. I added me@somedomain.com as an alternate in my google account. It still does not allow me to access the google doc. It says my google email doesn't have permission.

Isn't there a way to add a non google email to your google account and allow the non google email to access google docs? After all, the google doc was sent to me@somedomain.com and not the gmail email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about your account, account holder of the file who has sent you should provide the permission to other. And there are different types of permission in Google Doc.

1. Public: anyone with the link will be able to view/edit the document
2. People: submitted email holder can view/edit the document

So, you should ask the sender to allow/provide the access to your email or make it public.

Comment: What's the point of the alternate emails, then? I have >10 email accounts and it is tiresome and borderline unprofessional to have to constantly request access to documents that have *already* been shared with me by someone else. Seems like a very dysfunctional structure...